# Eth on unlocking auto transfers

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, geth-debugging, console, private

Facing a weird issue on geth console on my private network.
So, I was trying to unlock an account so that my web3 can access it.
As soon as I unlocked, all my ethers just vanished in seconds.. I could see some Submitted Transactions. However a scan over my explorer didn't yield any result. Any idea or someone faced a similar situation ?

Comment: I don't know what "Submitted Transactions" or "my explorer" mean, but without any other information, I would guess that your geth node was accessible to the internet, and a hacker took advantage of the unlocked account (perhaps not realizing this is a private Ethereum network, and thus the ether is not worth stealing).

Comment: @smarx Yes. It's testnet so the ethers are worthless. Yes, the node was RPC enabled. And open to internet.